# Получить Activity внутри DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, dialogfragment

Дело в том что в каждом `Activity` есть метод `bodyOnResume()` который делает проверку

```
public void bodyOnResume(){
    checkForResponseVacancy(model.getId());
}
```

А метод `bodyOnResume()` я вызываю внутри `dialogFragment` после `dismiss()`

```
mOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dismiss();
        ((MainBodyActivity) getActivity()).bodyOnResume();
    }
});
```

Этот вариант работает, но только для одного `MainBodyActivity`, а мне нужно чтобы был универсальный метод для получения название `Activity` вызвавшего это диалоговое окно.

Можно попробовать так:

```
if  (this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(VacancyBodyActivity.class.toString())) {
    ((VacancyBodyActivity) getActivity()).bodyOnResume();
} else if(this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(AnotherActivity.class.toString()))
    ((AnotherActivity) getActivity()).bodyOnResume();
}
......
// и дальше для 100500 Activity
```

Попробовал еще такой вариант:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).bodyOnResume();
```

Но тут не видит метод `bodyOnResume()`

**Вопрос**: Есть ли варианты, как решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Один из быстрых вариантов

Создайте интерфейс (как пример `OnResumeListener`) - с методом `bodyOnResume()`.
Имплементируйте этот интерфейс в те классы откуда вызывается ваш диалог.

дальше просто делайте проверку при закрытии диалога

```
if (getActivity() instanceof OnResumeListener){
  ((OnResumeListener) getActivity()).bodyOnResume();
}
```

готово.

Comment: Спасибо, выручили!